# Erro no foreach buscando um objeto com um unico array

Tags: php, array, objetos

Desenvolvi o seguinte código:

```
$soapClient = new \SoapClient($soapUrl, $options);
    $params = array('ListaDeCPF'=>$listaCPF, 'CPFUsuario'=>$cpfUsuario); 
    $theResponse = $soapClient->ConsultarCPFPDEC8789_SC($params);
    foreach ($theResponse->ConsultarCPFPDEC8789_SCResult->PessoaPerfilDEC8789 as $PessoaPerfilDEC8789){     
        echo "- Valor:" . $PessoaPerfilDEC8789->CPF;
    }
                
} catch (SoapFault $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();
    return;
}
```

O Dump do resultado vem assim:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'ConsultarCPFPDEC8789_SCResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'PessoaPerfilDEC8789' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[4]
              public 'CPF' => string '25321430777' (length=11)
              public 'Nome' => string 'MARIA APARECIDA' (length=21)
              public 'SituacaoCadastral' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'ResidenteExterior' => string '2' (length=1)                  
              public 'Erro' => string '' (length=0)
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[5]
              public 'CPF' => string '34307860850' (length=11)
              public 'Nome' => string 'JULIANO' (length=14)
              public 'SituacaoCadastral' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'ResidenteExterior' => string '2' (length=1)
              public 'Erro' => string '' (length=0)
```

E o retorno fo foreach vem assim:

- Valor:25321430888
- Valor:30347860850

Até ai tudo bem, mas quando o meu objeto tem um unico array como o dump abaixo:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'ConsultarCPFPDEC8789_SCResult' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'PessoaPerfilDEC8789' => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'CPF' => string '25321430888' (length=11)
          public 'Nome' => string 'MARIA APARECIDA LOPES' (length=21)
          public 'SituacaoCadastral' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'Erro' => string '' (length=0)
```

me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'CPF' of non-object in 
Call Stack
Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.2097  413936  {main}( )   ...\codigo.php:0
```

Não consigo saber como resolver. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: [Verifique se você tem um array](https://www.php.net/is_array) antes do foreach, e trate separadamente se não for – ou empacote o objeto dentro de um array para passar ao foreach.

Comment: `PessoaPerfilDEC8789` pode vir como um array de objetos ou um objeto, você tem que verificar e tratar isso ao usar as informações.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @Benilson, acredito que possa ser isso mesmo. Tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Juliano, já tentou o que sugeri no primeiro comentário? É justamente a mesma sugestão do @Benilson.

Comment: @bfavaretto, bom dia. Então,  estou quebrando a cabeça. Ontem pensei em fazer isso e dar um reset no array. vou testar hoje. Escrevo aqui mais tarde.

Answer (score -2):

O que acontece é o seguinte: quando consulto um unico CPF, ele me retorna um objeto. Quando consulto mais de um, a resposta vem como um array. Consegui tratar, utilizando a função gettype :

```
 if (gettype($retorno) == 'array') {
        echo ("é array");

 } elseif (gettype($retorno) == 'object'){
        echo ("é object");            
 }else{
   echo ("não reconhecido");
 }
```